# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^n \sin(\frac{x}{n})}$ converges for $a > 0$ in $[-a,a]$

Tags: calculus

Given:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^n \sin(\frac{x}{n})}$$

We need to show that it converges in $[-a,a]$ $\forall a >0$.

Now what I figured out:

> This is a function series summation. we need first to know what $C_n$ actually is and then do the Radius test.

But how do I exactly get it in the general form ?

Comment: Do you know the alternating series test?

Comment: Note that $\sin(x/n)=x/n+O\left(\frac{x^3}{n^3}\right)$.  Can you finish now?

Answer (score 2):

What you should realise is that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\sin\left( \frac{x}{n} \right)$ converges iff $\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\sin\left( \frac{x}{n} \right)$ converges
where $N\in\mathbb{N}$ is such that $N \leq \vert a \vert$ and $N+1 > \vert a \vert$ as changing a finite amount of summands has no effect on the convergence. Now you should carefully argue that you may apply the Leibniz criterion.

Comment: Without proving first that the series converges, what you wrote makes no sense.

Comment: Of course, but that was what I wanted the OP to think about. However I have edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

for $n \ge |a|$,  $\sin \left( \frac{x}{n} \right)$ has same sign as $x$, so we can use [Jordan's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_inequality) and then use [Leibniz criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) to argue that the series converges.

Comment: How does Jordan's inequality show that $\sin(x/n)$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n\sin\left(\frac xn\right)&=\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n\left(\frac xn\right)+\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n\left(\sin\left(\frac xn\right)-\frac xn\right)\\\\
&=x\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^n}n+\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n\left(\sin\left(\frac xn\right)-\frac xn\right)\tag1
\end{align}$$

The first summation on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is the alternating harmonic sum, which converges as $N\to\infty$.

For the second summation on the right-hand side of $(1)$ we have the estimate

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n\left(\sin\left(\frac xn\right)-\frac xn\right)\right|&\le \sum_{n=1}^N \left|\sin\left(\frac xn\right)-\frac xn\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{|x|^3}6\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n^3}
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}$ converges, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\sin\left(\frac xn\right)-\frac xn\right)$ is absolutely convergent.

Putting it all together shows that the series of interest converges for all $x$.

Comment: The last inequalty is unclear, I'd say that: $\sum_{n=1}^N |\sin(\frac xn)-\frac xn|
\le 2*x \sum_{n=1}^N |\frac 1n| $ which converges for N goes to infinity and especially for $N=2*x$ and that would avoid questioning the power 3 and the $\frac 1 6$ in the last inequality.

Comment: @Vitali Pom It is coming from Taylor's formula. The one you gave is not convergent since $\sum\nolimits_1^N {\frac{1}{n}}  = \log N + \mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: Thanks @Gary I see my mistake now, indeed the $(-1)^n$ needed to be added there. Since I cannot edit and I don't want to rewrite the formula, I'll leave here this comment for help. With the $(-1)^n$ of course it converges. Thanks though for clarifying.